Бот поддержки. Нужно чтобы после того как пользователь пише сообщение,оно отпровлялось мне. Но у меня неполучилось,и выдает ошибку
import asyncio

from aiogram.fsm.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.filters import StateFilter
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters.command import Command
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder
import kbb
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery,Message
class CreatePreviewOrder(StatesGroup):
    SET_TEXT = State()
    SUBMIT = State()
bot = Bot(token="7270981240:AAHWIaBaN_PDOQbMGaK7lEpgxvBlCqjc_HE")
admin_id = 1683941106
dp = Dispatcher()
@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer (
    text = "Здравстуйте,это поддержка бота storm\n\nЕсли вы хотите отправить сообщение в поддежржку нажмите кнопку 'да'",
        reply_markup = kbb.support_starter
    )
@dp.callback_query('send_help_mess')
async def qqq(state: FSMContext):
    await CallbackQuery.message.edit_text(
        text=f"✏️ Напиши свой вопрос/ошибку\n"
             f"✅ После того как ты напишешь своё сооьщение\n"
             f" Оно перешлётся поддержке\n\n"
             f" Присылать можно только фото"
    )
    await state.set_state(CreatePreviewOrder.SET_TEXT)
@dp.message(StateFilter(CreatePreviewOrder.SET_TEXT))
async def set_text(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(text=message.html_text)
    await message.answer(
        text=f"❔ Отправить сообщение? По нажатию на кнопку «Да» - сообщение перешлётся в техподдержку",
        reply_markup=(
            InlineKeyboardBuilder()
            .button(text="Да", callback_data="yes")
            .button(text="Нет", callback_data="no")
            .as_markup()
        )
    )
    await state.set_state(CreatePreviewOrder.SUBMIT)
@dp.callback_query(StateFilter(CreatePreviewOrder.SUBMIT),'yes')
async def submit_yes(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await callback.message.edit_text(
        text="✅ Твоё сообщение отправлено",
        reply_markup=kbb.support_starter
    )
    await callback.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=1683941106,
        text="Новое сообщение")
    await callback.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=1683941106,
        text=f"<b>ID:</b> <code>{Message.from_user.id}</code>\n"
             f"<b>ТЗ:</b>\n"
             f"{Message.text}"
    )
async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass


Какую ошибку? .

2 ошибки. 1)raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
TypeError: 'send_help_mess' is not a callable object 2)TypeError: unsupported callable

@eey Добавьте полный текст ошибки, включая traceback, в вопрос, нажав Править
